# rails, Chrome Error Message on AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I'm making an AJAX request to the server, and keep getting this error message in Chrome:

```
jquery-1.4.3.min.js:31Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
threadss:-1Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/html.
```

I'm using Rails 3. Anyone seen this?

Comment: We need some more information.